# Search for a specific word in html file in Python

Tags: python, html

I want to count how many times a specific word can be found in a html file. The html file is downloaded from an url:

```
with urlopen(url) as response:
   source = response.read()
```

Since there are no specific lines in a html file I am  having trouble going through the file in search for the specific word... Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Yes - [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: "there are no specific lines in a html file" what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
num_occ = source.count("your_specific_word")
```

Comment: I get TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'. And when I convert the word into a bytes object the count is 0 even though I know it is not...

Answer (score 0):

So if are looking for a web scraping tool then go with [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

Else you could just calculate the count by the number of occurrences in the text by simply using count

```
with urlopen(url) as response:
   source = response.read()
noOfOccurances = source.count(searchWord)
```

[Python string count](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-count/)

Comment: @brukernavn I think you might have some encoding issue, please read the file in utf8 or please attached a sample of the text which is not working in the question.